# tmLanguage: how to match custom patterns in match

Tags: vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm developing a VS Code extension for a small language that I made.

In my `lang.tmLanguage.json`,
let's say that in the repository I have defined patterns `#A` and `#B`.

I want to create the following pattern

```json
{
  "X": {
    "match": "start <#A> <#B>"
  }
}
```

Good examples of what I'm trying to do would be
`if <#if-condition> <#statement>`
or `class [\w\d_]+ <#inheritance>? <class-body>`

How to embed patterns from the repository in other patterns?